# In SQL how to get percent of group by date?

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate a SQL query from the following data in which results in the percentage of total sales by region for each date.   There can be multiple entries for the same region on the same date that I need to sum

| Date | Region | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1, 2021 | Northeast | 100 |
| Jan 1, 2021 | Northeast | 80 |
| Jan 1, 2021 | Midwest | 75 |
| Jan 1, 2021 | West. | 120 |
| Jan 9, 2021 | Northeast | 110 |
| Jan 9, 2021 | Northeast | 90 |
| Jan 9, 2021 | Midwest | 55 |
| Jan 9, 2021 | West | 80 |

I've tried:

```
SELECT "Date","Region",SUM("Sales") as "TotalUSD",
      SUM("Sales") * 100 / SUM(SUM("Sales"))  OVER () AS Percentage
FROM "sales_db"."sales_table"
GROUP BY "Date","Region"
```

but this is not giving the correct percentages by region by date.  I think it might be giving the percentage of total by region over all dates.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would the percentage for 2021-01-01 and Northeast be 48% or ~25%? It would be best if you added the desired result to the question too. And tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using. (2) Provide sample data, desired results, and explain what "not giving the correct percentages" means. What results do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the proportion within a date, then `date` should be in the `partition by`:

```
SELECT "Date", "Region", SUM("Sales") as "TotalUSD",
       SUM("Sales") * 100.0 / SUM(SUM("Sales"))  OVER (PARTITION BY "Date") AS Percentage
FROM "sales_db"."sales_table"
GROUP BY "Date", "Region";
```

Note:  I strongly advise you to get rid of the double quotes in the identifier names.  If necessary, re-create the table.  All the double quotes just make the query harder to write and to read.

Also, I added a `.0`.  Some databases do integer division, which can also throw results off a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `partition by` clause as follows:

```
SELECT "Date","Region",SUM("Sales") as "TotalUSD",
      SUM("Sales") * 100 / SUM(SUM("Sales"))  OVER (partition by "Region") AS Percentage
FROM "sales_db"."sales_table"
GROUP BY "Date","Region"
```

Comment: hmmm, that still doesn't generate the expected output.  Maybe I need to partition by "Date"?    I'm trying to see what percent each region was of sales on that date.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned the database or its version. So, here is a code given below for SQL SERVER 2012 and MYSQL 8.0

```
CREATE TABLE MySales(Date DATETIME,Region Varchar(20),Sales Decimal(18,2));--Table Schema

WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT Date,Region,Sales,SUM(Sales) OVER() TotalUSD,
           SUM(Sales)  OVER (partition by Region,Date ) AS TotalSumOfGroup
    FROM MySales
    )
    SELECT *,((Sales/TotalSumOfGroup)*100) Parcentage FROM CTE
    ORDER BY Region
```

**Note:** Please check [MySQL Code in DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8vausksYa11eTiXuWAQQbv/1) link with your data.